# How to change value of SVG text?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg texts array:

```
var texts = []; //for svg text objects

function create() {
  for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
     var d = 10;
     var n = d-1;
     var text = document.createElementNS(NS, 'text'); 
     var data = document.createTextNode(d); 
     text.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "text"+i); 
     texts.push(text);
     var t = texts[i];
     document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(t); 
     change(n);
     d--;
  }
}

function change(n) {
   //change 
}
```

how to change value of text "d" -> "n"? 
I use already node.nodeValue but doesn't working.

```
 t.firstChild.value = n;
```

i don't want use another js library.
Is there simple way to change value?

Answer (score 2):

To change the text displayed in a SVG text element, you can set the nodeValue of the child text node of the SVG text element. For example...

```
var svgTextElement = document.getElementById("text1");
var textNode = svgTextElement.childNodes[0];
textNode.nodeValue = "New text.";
```

Note that your code was not adding the text node to the svg text element. You need to call appendChild() method. For example...

```
var text = document.createElementNS(NS, 'text'); 
var data = document.createTextNode(d);
text.appendChild(data);
```

Comment: can i textNode.nodeValue = n; ?

Comment: You can assign a number value to nodeValue. In which case, the number value will be automatically converted to a string value.